# SpringBoot shedlock Without time Interval

Tags: spring-boot, scheduler, shedlock

I am running Spring boot  application with 2 instances.Here i am going to use scheduler to run my application.For avoiding Scheduler not to run in two instances at same time using schlock .but schlock i have to mention for atleastfor or atmostfor .My problem is i dont want to release the lock based on time because since  using batch application with rest call dont know when my scheduler get complete process.Kindly provide any suggestion running my scheduler with one instance at time without time constraint.

Answer (score 0):

ShedLock requires lockAtMostFor for cases when the node dies. You can try [KeepAliveLockProvider](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock#keepalivelockprovider) to automatically extend the lock.